# Avoid concatenating words words when reading xml text in R

Tags: r, xml

I'm working with long text documents in tei-xml, using R. I want to manipulate the raw text for word counts and so on.

When I try

```
library(xml2)

x <- read_xml("<text><p>Some text</p><p>another bit of text</p>
              <p>and some more 
              text.</p></text>")
x_text <- xml_text(x)
x_text
# [1] "Some textanother bit of textand some more \n              text."
```

there are two problems with the text it returns.

1) When the xml tags are removed, words are concatenated. How do I avoid "textanother"?

2) Line breaks appear as \n. This is easily solved with `grep`, but I wonder if I can avoid it in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select all the text nodes then paste them together so there is a space between them

```
paste(xml_text(xml_find_all(x, "//text()")), collapse=" ")
```

Or you could avoid the paste to keep them separate. `xml_text` has an option to trim whitespace but it would not remove whitespace from the middle of the string which is where your newline occurs. If you just want to remove multiple whitespace characters with a single space you could do

```
gsub("\\s+", " ",paste(xml_text(xml_find_all(x, "//text()")), collapse=" "))
# [1] "Some text another bit of text and some more text."
```